# How can I change the delete message "This action cannot be undone." in a specific content type?

Tags: 6, forms, nodes

I have a version drupal 6 and I need to change the next message that is shown  when I am going to delete a content:

"This action cannot be undone."

I need to change this message only for some content types, not in all.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code (it works for me - Drupal 6):

```
function module_change_default_messages_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && arg(2) == 'delete') {
      $node = node_load(arg(1));   
          if ($form_id == 'node_delete_confirm') {
              if($node->type == 'story'){
                $form['description'] = array('#value' => "here replace to \"this action cannot be undone\"");
              } else if($node->type == 'page'){
                $form['description'] = array('#value' => "this action cannot be undone");
              }
          }
      }
}
```

or you can use the PHP [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement for more content types.

Comment: This code works for me.  It's a great idea this code.  It's very practice and simple.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it in Drupal 6:

http://drupal.org/node/736352

If you have multiple content types you wish to change that message, then I would suggest unifying the code from that link into 1 function, instead of multiple functions per type.

I hope that helps, let me know if you were able to solve it.

Comment: The code suggested in the link describes how to change the behavior of the button 'delete' but I want to change the message no more.  I ask you how to change only the text no the behavior of the button 'delete'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- Implement `hook_menu_alter()` to alter the menu callback associated with the "node/%node/delete" menu item
- Implement the new menu callback

  ```
  function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
    if (isset($items['node/%node/delete'])) {
      $items['node/%node/delete']['page arguments'] = array('mymodule_node_delete_confirm', 1);
      $items['node/%node/delete']['file path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule');
      $items['node/%node/delete']['file'] = 'mymodule.admin.inc';

      // If the function is defined in the module file, you can use the following line instead of the last two lines.
      // unset($items['node/%node/delete']['file']);
    }
  }

  function mymodule_node_delete_confirm(&$form_state, $node) {
    $form['nid'] = array(
      '#type' => 'value', 
      '#value' => $node->nid,
    );

    return confirm_form($form, 
      t('Are you sure you want to delete %title?', array('%title' => $node->title)), 
      isset($_GET['destination']) ? $_GET['destination'] : 'node/' . $node->nid, 
      t('This action cannot be undone.'), // Change this message with the one you prefer. 
      t('Delete'), 
      t('Cancel')
    );
  }

  function mymodule_node_delete_confirm_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    if ($form_state['values']['confirm']) {
      node_delete($form_state['values']['nid']);
    } 

    $form_state['redirect'] = '<front>';
  }
  ```

As `mymodule_node_delete_confirm()` gets the node object, you can check the content type of that node using `$node->type`; basing on the value of that property, you can change the values for the confirmation form.

Comment: There is a missing `$` at the first line. `&items` should be corrected as `&$items`.

Comment: You're welcome. Do you know how to achieve this by Drupal 7?

Comment: The code I shown in my answer is still valid for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

In drupal 7, it is easy to override any message.
Use following form alter code.

```
function modulename_form_node_delete_confirm_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['description']['#markup']='Are you sure? Once deleted, the content of this tale cannot be recovered.';
  return $form;
}
```