# How to change the delete Message "Are you sure you want to delete" in Drupal 7

Tags: nodes

I want to change the message "Are you sure you want to delete" to simple "delete".
Can someone explain how I can do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the delete message "This action cannot be undone." in a specific content type?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10747/how-can-i-change-the-delete-message-this-action-cannot-be-undone-in-a-specifi)

Comment: I see that thread and I do not understand how this code work. For example... have I to make a "mymodule.admin.inc" file and what code shoulb be in this file if it is needed? I ask on that thread but this question was deleted by Clive :-(

Comment: What message are you talking about? There are so many things in drupal you can delete that have a similar message to that so you will have to say what you are deleting.

Comment: I have seen that thread "How can I change the delete message “This action cannot be undone.” in a specific content type? " And ask there how to make a module from that. For example... have I to create a "mymodule.admin.inc" file and what code shoulb be in this file if it is needed?. That was the question that I ask in this thread. Thanks for your help!

Comment: But you didn't ask that question in this thread. The question above asks something else and is vague. Best if you update your question above to be asking what you want to know.

Answer (score 3):

One option (that requires no coding) is to use the [String Overrides](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module.

It allows you to replace any string with another string that is passed though the [`t()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) function, though a nice easy to use GUI.

The other option is to use [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). For more details on that see the question that Rupesh linked to.

Comment: Have you test it with the module String override? For me this string was not changed... :-( .

Comment: See Free Radicals answer...

Answer (score 2):

The term "Are you sure you want to delete" does not appear on its own in any of the strings embedded in the function `t()`, so you *can't* use [String Overrides](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) to change this in a single replacement rule.

Instead it appears in constructs such as:

```
Are you sure you want to delete the forum %name?
Are you sure you want to delete %title?
Are you sure you want to delete %category?
Are you sure you want to delete the block %name?
Are you sure you want to delete the term %title?
Are you sure you want to delete the vocabulary %title?
```

(and about 20 more on my site - exact number depends on what modules you've installed).

The [String Overrides](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module will only replace the *complete* string that is passed through `t()`.

In other words, you cant feed "Are you sure you want to delete" to String Overrides and expect a result, you need to feed "Are you sure you want to delete the forum %name?" and repleace it with "Delete the forum %name?" to have the effect you've after.

You then need to repeat the procedure with *every* string containing the words to have see this universally applied.

If you find it cumbersome to repeat all these strings, you can implement `hook_menu_alter()` to alter the menu callback associated with the "node/%node/delete" menu item.

Comment: I had test it but this does not overide this string.

Comment: Thnaks sooo much... now it works!

Comment: One small question: I found this for the edit form <em>Edit @type</em> @title And it does not work with string overrides. have I to do something to make it work?

Comment: Looks like it has a trailing space: "`<em>Edit @type</em> @title `".  Try adding a space.